# Vue + Vuex: variable stored in component saves changes even after leaving and coming back

Tags: vue.js, vuex

I am assigning a variable in my component to a variable stored in vuex (let's say it's empty at the beginning) like

```
export default {
  name: "Step1",
  [...]
  data() {
    return {
      participants: this.$store.state.participants,
  [...]
```

later I work with this variable and add something like

```
  [...]
  methods: {
    add: function() {
      this.participants.push("foo");
    },
    [...]
```

I never update the variable in the store as I double-check on devtools. I expect this behaviour and expect the variable to be empty again after moving to another route and coming back. But somehow the variable in the component still contains "foo" despite the variable in the store is empty.

I'd appreciate a hint what I don't understand in Vue, it's driving me crazy.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/6605700/381282

Comment: Thanks, I was thinking about that. But why is it not showing the updated value in vue devtools?

Comment: DevTools can be misleading. Especially when yo are not using mutation to change the state but change it directly like in your case...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to some help here I found a workaround:

Make a local copy of the variable in the component, e.g. with using spread syntax for iterable objects and simple assignments for primitive datatypes, and update the whole object after working with it.

Check this to for get an understanding for call-by-value and call-by-reference in JavaScript: stackoverflow.com/a/6605700/381282

```
<template>
  [...]
</template>

<script>
export default {
  name: "Step1",
  [...]
  data() {
    return {
      participants: [...this.$store.state.participants]
  [...]
  methods:
    updateParticipants: function() {
      $store.commit('updateParticipants', this.participants)
  [...]
<script>
```

Answer (score 0):

You should never change the store state directly like that. As stated in the [docs](https://vuex.vuejs.org/guide/mutations.html):

> The only way to actually change state in a Vuex store is by committing a mutation.

So in your store, you have to add a mutation method, like so:

```
mutations: {
    addParticipant(state, participant) {
      state.participants.push(participant);
    }
}
```

And call that: `this.$store.commit('addParticipant', 'Foo')`

Comment: Actually I was thinking to get the variable from the store, use it in the html (v-for or whatever), change it (add or whatever) and finally update the store like you suggested with this.$store.commit('updateParticipants', this.participants'). Is this a wrong approach?

Comment: Not really! You could just make a local copy (`participants: [...this.$store.state.participants]` will copy the store array), edit that, and then update the store later.